# dropped out from school on schengen long term student visa

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, study, long-stay-visas

I was admitted to a school on schengen long term student visa(multiple entry), but I had to drop out after 6 months. Now I went to another Schengen state, and see good schools, I like to join, how do I proceed, if I get admission from State 2, can I change my visa. Please note my residency right now is with state 1
its France and Spain, state 1 and state 2 respectively

Comment: The rules for long-stay visas are up to each Schengen member to set for themselves. They are not harmonized between member states, so it will be impossible to answer meaningfully without knowing which two countries are involved.

Comment: (Also, questions about student visas belong better on our sister site [Expats.SE], which deals with moving abroad to _live_ rather than simply temporary traveling).

Comment: its France and Spain, state 1 and state 2 respectively